# Java: NIO version of HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, webclient, nio, httpurlconnection

I have to download many many web pages and I am going to use `HttpURLConnection` for doing because it is very convenient.

However, I don't want to use thread-based downloading. I wish to use `async download` and still use HttpURLConnection.

Is there a way for that? I really need `java nio`, but don't want to write the socket client by myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/) or [vert.x](http://vertx.io/); the latter is based on the former.

Comment: Hello. I have had a look at netty. It is much more complicated than I need. I just need an asynch http downloader where I can give a delegate that if the downloading finishes, then do something declared in the delegate. could you please give me more hints?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of hints.   I only sent this two hours ago.  Are you certain that in that short period of time that you've digested Netty well enough to decide that you couldn't accomplish what you want with a subset of its capabilities?  You're smarter than me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [async-http-client](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client).
From the README:

> Async Http Client library purpose is to allow Java applications to
>   easily execute HTTP requests and asynchronously process the HTTP
>   responses.

Comment: that seems to have moved here:  https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client